# git auto-complete for *branches* at the command line?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, auto-complete, git

On my Linux machine I have autocomplete *for branches* with Git.

[Note we are talking about git branch completion, *not* bash completion (e.g. commands, files, etc).  Thus NOT [Lane's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/92637/145449) at all]

For example I can type `git checkout`+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and get a list of branches.

Or I can type `git checkout feb*`+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to get all branches that begin with "feb".

How can I get this functionality on a Mac?

I tried downloading and running `bash-completion/bash_completion` and `bash-completion/bash_completion.sh.in` but no joy.  The first gave error messages about `declare: -A invalid_option`.  The second gave no errors.   When I `git checkout`+<kbd>TAB</kbd> though I am still getting a list of files in the directory, not branches.  I am in the project root.

Auto-complete for directories and bash commands are working ok, so it's specific to Git.

Comment: I just joined this community so I can't yet answer, but I found "oh-my-zsh" to be super super helpful and I really like the UI:  
https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh  
This is, of course, for people using zsh. I'm assuming it doesn't work for bash...

Comment: Now that the Mac uses zsh instead of bash [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58517668/575530) may prove useful.

Comment: for zsh users: `echo 'autoload -Uz compinit && compinit' >> ~/.zshrc && . ~/.zshrc` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513873/git-tab-completion-not-working-in-zsh-on-mac)

Comment: 1. Go to this url https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion
2. Follow the instructions in the completion file that fits your usage, whether its bash or zsh

Comment: I tired a few answers but none worked, so I tried the suggestion at https://www.macinstruct.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-git-tab-autocomplete-on-your-mac/.  Same as JillAndMe's suggestion.  Then it worked

Answer (score 612, accepted):

Ok, so I needed the *git* autocompletion script.

I got that from [this url](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) using the following command in the Terminal app:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -o ~/.git-completion.bash
```

No need to worry about what directory you're in when you run this as your home directory(`~`) is used with the target.

Then I added to my `~/.bash_profile` file the following 'execute if it exists' code:

```
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  . ~/.git-completion.bash
fi
```

Update: I'm making these bits of code more concise to shrink down my `.bashrc` file, in this case I now use:

```
test -f ~/.git-completion.bash && . $_
```

Note: `$_` means the last argument to the previous command. so `. $_` means run it - "it" being `.git-completion.bash` in this case

This still works on both Ubuntu and OSX and on machines without the script `.git-completion.bash` script.

Now `git` <kbd>Tab</kbd> (actually it's `git` <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> ) works like a charm!

p.s.: If this doesn't work off the bat, you may need to run `chmod u+x ~/.git-completion.bash` to grant yourself the necessary permission:

- `chmod` is the command that modifies file permissions
- `u` means the user that owns the file, by default its creator, i.e. you
- `+` means set/activate/add a permission
- `x` means execute permission, i.e. the ability to run the script

Comment: Yep, restarting terminal after adding the bash script made it work. I was sitting here wondering why it kept trying to autocomplete to my `Models` folder when I hit `m` `Tab` to make it autocomplete to `master`.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48862/10043 for a different tip

Comment: If the accepted answer isn't working for anyone then try this:
`source ~/.bash_profile` after pasting the code. Restarting the terminal will also do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! I tried some other stuff but nothing worked (including this https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion). Your solution worked like a charm ;)

Comment: (you don't have brew `git` but Apple default `git`) `brew install git` and restart terminal for those who are facing weird error like `git checunknown option: --list-cmds=list-mainporcelain,others,nohelpers,alias,list-complete,config
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]`

Comment: I did this on an older computer, copied my bash_profile to my new computer, but autocomplete did not work. I forgot I had to `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -o ~/.git-completion.bash` Thanks again :)

Comment: @Sachin I posted the solution for the your problem here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/350790/18664

Comment: One interesting change you could make to the shell script is test if the file is not there, if not, then curl the script and source it.

Comment: Resolve in zsh by following the answer.                                                                       
               https://stackoverflow.com/a/26479426/5293521

Comment: Does anyone know how to make it show only the local branches? It's showing all the remote branches as well.

Comment: For MacOS Catalina, this doesn’t work anymore. Solution in this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/381958/81900

Comment: `git-completion.bash` is obsolete: MacOS users should use the zsh completion wrapper for git `git-completion.zsh` instead: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh

Comment: @Nefeline I got the same error. Could you point me to the correct answer on how to use the zsh wrapper?

Comment: this resolved  git autocompletion. thanks

Comment: I was getting errors with autocomplete script when running `source ~/.zshrc` on M1 Mac due to updated Homebrew location. This fixed it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71411014/76672 and now GIT autocomplete works. You shouldn't need to manually load git-completion file.

Comment: Earlier comment by Ben to use "source". Indeed, on macos 12.5.1 vanilla bash it does not work; reverted back to:  test -f ~/.git-completion.bash && . $_

Comment: For zsh, follow the below solution after doing the steps on the accepted answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58517668/3886821

Answer (score 122):

Some people prefer to use a package manager to automate the installing, updating, and configuring of Mac OS packages. I am a fan of package managers, and I think Homebrew is the best package manager for Mac OS (some would say it's the de-facto Mac OS package manager).

Once you have installed Homebrew, you can simply install **git** along with **bash-completion** with `brew install git bash-completion`.

You'll then need to put the following in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash ]; then
  . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
fi
```

(Note: If this install fails with a 404 error, and you already have git installed, just remove the git part of this brew install)

[More info on installing git and bash-completion with brew here.](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion)

Comment: Adding `git` and adding `bash-completion` is not at all the same as adding `.git-completion.bash`  They are different programs and they do quite different things - one does bash command autocompletion and the other does git command autocompletion and 'nair the twain will meet ;)

Comment: working like a charm, many thanks. Could you please explain what is the use of script that you have got me added in `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Despite what others have said about this answer, it is the one that made git autocomplete work in terminal.

Comment: Note that the lines to add into the `~/.bash_profile` were specified for me in the output of homebrew. I used those instead of the lines above. Then you need to reload the bash profile in each terminal window you would like to use autocompletion in, by using the command `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I did not particularly want to install Git from Homebrew; for the record, the [`bash-completion` Brew formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/bash-completion) provides Bash completion for much more than just Git.

Answer (score 43):

Run this on terminal:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -o ~/.git-completion.bash
```

Then, do this:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Add this lines:

```
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  . ~/.git-completion.bash
fi
```

That's all. This worked for me.

Comment: (2nd step) If anyone prefers to open the bash_profile with a text editor, just do this: open -e .bash_profile

Comment: On a virgin Mac OS High Sierra, the `~/.bash_profile` file doesn't exist. That's fine just create the file and place that `if` script in there and save. Reload your shell after and it will work.

Comment: This worked for me. Instead of vi (That I always struggle with) just do 

open -e ~/.bash_profile

Comment: For the 2nd step you will need [this link](http://itproguru.com/expert/2016/11/how-to-exit-quit-vi-editor-without-saving-changes-step-by-step/)

Comment: Useful accompanying link if you have alias(es) set up for git -- https://gist.github.com/JuggoPop/10706934

Answer (score 28):

`git` and `git-completion.bash` already come with macOS command line tools (`xcode-select --install`). To enable bash autocomplete, add this to your `~/.bash_profile`.

```bash
[ -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash ] \
    && . /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash
```

This will also enable autocomplete for git branches.

Comment: Pretty sure I've command line tools installed, but that file doesn't exist in my case. Happy to go with brew though (and since my git is with brew also, perhaps wiser too).

Comment: Thanks! IMO, this should be the answer with the green check mark.

Comment: This is the most straightforward solution and it works for me

Comment: This worked for me - although I used a slightly different format.  
```if [ -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash ]; then
    . /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash > /dev/null
fi```

Comment: for me the answer worked but after adding the given line to `~/.bash_profile` do not forget to also run `source ~/.bash_profile` (especially if you create the `~/.bash_profile` file for the first time)

Comment: Straightforward and correct. Remember you must install Xcode commandline tools first to have this work, use `xcode-select --install` from Terminal.app and restart when done.

Comment: This is outdated: `this script is obsolete, please see git-completion.zsh`

Answer (score 26):

## Git autocompletion on Catalina and newer (using Homebrew)

macOs changed from **bash** to **zsh** as default shell starting with Catalina.
So you will need specific autocomplete scripts for zsh.

Here is how to install them with Homebrew:

```
brew install zsh-completions
```

Brew's [zsh-completion](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/zsh-completions#default) does in fact include git-completion.

To activate autocompletion you then need to add a small block of code to your  `~/.zshrc`. You may have to create that file in your user folder if it does not already exist. **Note:** The output of the above installation script will tell you exactly what code to add, so read that carefully and copy from there in case it has been updated since my writing here.

```
if type brew &>/dev/null; then
  FPATH=$(brew --prefix)/share/zsh-completions:$FPATH

  autoload -Uz compinit
  compinit
fi
```

**Important:**
When installation has finished, **read** the output of the installation script.
It will instruct you not only to add code to .zshrc but also give you advice on additional actions that might be necessary, like force rebuilding zcompdump. But most likely you will not need the additional steps.

Comment: The terminal show an annoying message each time that it's opened: 
```zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?``` 
But it works!

Comment: I just joined this community so I can't yet answer, but I found "oh-my-zsh" to be super super helpful and I really like the UI:
https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh
This is, of course, for people using zsh. I'm assuming it doesn't work for bash...

Comment: @AdolfoCorrea you can resolve the warning message by entering the following command:
compaudit | xargs chmod g-w

Comment: I get the annyoing message + it doesn't work...

Comment: Git completions are part of the Homebrew `git` package, not `zsh-completions` (which has completions for Git extensions, like [Git Flow](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/0.33.0/src/_git-flow), among others). So, `brew install git`, which tells you it installs completions, and then follow [Homebrew's Shell Completion guide](https://docs.brew.sh/Shell-Completion).

Answer (score 8):

Here's what's confusing some of you: you have brew or ports installed, but you are using an the system git in `/usr/bin/`. To check this:

```
which git
```

If you see `/usr/bin/git` then either brew isn't correctly configured, or you've not installed git via brew.

If you install git via brew, then enabling bash completions for brew will also enable bash completions for git. This is because `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion` actually sources everything in `/usr/local/bash_completion.d`, and the brew package for git installs a git completion script there.

Comment: This makes sense, but how would you "enable bash completions for brew"? You're missing how to do that, this should be part of your answer

Comment: I just did this (it works, thank you) via https://www.simplified.guide/macos/bash-completion, but the auto completion is a couple seconds delayed... odd

Answer (score 4):

You could install bash and git from MacPorts with the "bash_completion" option enabled. It is probably the easiest way of maintaining both git and the completions up-to-date.

http://denis.tumblr.com/post/71390665/adding-bash-completion-for-git-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard

To install MacPorts: http://www.macports.org/install.php/

**Additional info**

As for locating the completion settings on your Linux system, have a look in /etc/bash_completion.d/git (it is a long file). Copying that by itself probably won't work, though, as it is designed to be sourced by the completion framework through /etc/bash_completion (which is sourced from /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh; files in /etc/profile.d are sourced from /etc/profile).

Answer (score 3):

For macOS Catalina+, in `zsh`:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh -o ~/.git-completion.zsh
```

Then update your `~/.zshrc` with:

```
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.zsh ]; then
    . ~/.git-completion.zsh
fi
```

Comment: Now I get `c:8: command not found: __git_aliased_command`whenever I try to autocomplete...

Comment: It complains about line 48 of the script: `no such file or directory: 
_git:19: command not found: _default`

Answer (score 2):

If your git completion is partially broken, even after sourcing `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash`, you may just need to update your git version.

For example, when I typed `git check` + `TAB`, it would correctly autocomplete `git checkout`. But when I typed `git checkout` + `TAB`, it did not display the list of branches, only `HEAD`.

The fix for me was to update my `git` version. I was on 2.7.0, which apparently was not compatible with the latest `git-completion.bash`. I ran `brew upgrade git`, which updated it to 2.13.0, and now it properly autocompletes my branch names.

Comment: I was getting the same issue, but I had to run `brew upgrade git` and `brew link git`  (with override enabled)

Comment: Thanks for the catch @Tope. I have changed `update` to `upgrade`.

Answer (score 2):

By far, the best reference I've found to solve this very issue is on [SpinDance](https://spindance.com/enable-git-tab-completion-bash-mac-os-x/), by [Connor Livingston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732147/conorliv):

> If the **git-completion.bash** script doesn’t exist on your machine, please retrieve it from the link I provided above (which is [this](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)) and save it to your local machine in a new file called **git-completion.bash** in the */usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/* directory. If the **git-completion.bash** script exists on your machine, but is not in the */usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/* directory, we should create a copy of it in that directory. A quick ***sudo cp /current/path/to/your/git-completion.bash /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash*** should do the trick. For those who are curious about the */usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/* directory: it’s for storing new completion commands, and you may have to create it if it doesn’t already exist on your machine.
>
> At this point the git-completion.bash script should exist on your local machine in the */usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/* directory. Now we’ll plug the git completion script into bash by pointing to it from *~/.bash_profile*.
>
> Note: the tilde in the previous sentence refers to the home directory on your computer. Add the following line to *~/.bash_profile*: **source /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash** and save. The final step is to reload your bash profile. You can achieve this by running **source ~/.bash_profile** in your current bash session.

Answer (score 2):

Tried it and it works well for branches but when you do `git st` + `tab` then it shows the error like this

> unknown option: --list-cmds=list-mainporcelain,others,nohelpers,alias,list-complete,config usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C ] [-c =] [--exec-path[=]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path] [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare] [--git-dir=] [--work-tree=] [--namespace=]  []

Searched the internet and found that `--list-cmds` in `.git-completion.bash` was in latest version of the git and on my mac the git version was `2.17.2`

## Here are the solutions

#### Solution 1

1. Check the version of the git by using `git --version` command
2. Then put the same version number in the url as I did

   ```
   curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/v2.17.2/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -o ~/.git-completion.bash
   ```
3. Then follow the same steps as in the top answer, put the below code in `~/.bash_profile`

   ```
   if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
     . ~/.git-completion.bash
   fi
   ```

#### Solution 2

You should try to update the git version to the latest then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Install [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) and set zsh as your default shell and thank me later :)

Comment: I have done that, precisely in the hope of not having to deal with it -- still no branch suggestions after hitting tab

Comment: You actually **do not need oh-my-zsh**, or even any separate plugin system at all! Git completion comes out of the box, you just have to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

Most users will have `git` installed as part of xcode command line tools at `/usr/bin/git` and bash completion rules for git will be available at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash`.

In this case no need to install git from Homebrew or source git completion rules from raw.githubusercontent.com. Just create a symlink as follows:

```
cd /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/
ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash git
```

Note: make sure you've installed and configured `bash-completion` package from Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

See [appendix A1.7 of the Git handbook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Zsh):

> Zsh also ships with a tab-completion library for Git. To use it, simply run `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit` in your `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to switch to a different shell, the `fish` shell has this feature built in.  It also has some other handy features such as autocomplete while typing.

Answer (score -2):

Locate your `.bashrc` file.

Open it and add this line at the bottom:

`source /etc/bash_completion.d/git`

Comment: I don't have anything an `/etc/bash_completion.d/` folder, on a relatively new system (OSX 10.10.3).

Comment: Try creating it.

Comment: Not bash_completion, git_completion which does different stuff.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant It works. Trust Me. ;) http://www.prowrestlingtees.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/470x246/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/t/r/trust_me_1_2.png

Comment: @crmpicco Could you please provide instructions for creating `/etc/bash_completion.d/git`? It would make your answer more valuable.

Comment: `brew install git bash-completion` as explained at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/92637/136365 will get you these files, albeit in a different location