# git auto-complete branches with checkout alias

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, git, auto-complete

There's [this neat script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55875/git-auto-complete-for-branches-at-the-command-line) to autocomplete git branches.

It works fine with `git checkout <tab>`.

But, I want to take it further. I have a checkout alias: `alias co='git co'`.

How can I make branch autocompletion work using `co <branch>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this in my .bashrc which works *okay*:

```
alias gco="git checkout"
__git_complete gco _git_checkout
```

If you open up that *neat script* you'll see method names like `__git_checkout`. You can get completion for each of those methods using this method.

Unfortunately, commands like `git pull` don't play nice when you try to tab complete the branch name (the second argument), for example given this alias:

```
alias gpl="git pull"
__git_complete gpl _git_pull
```

This behavior occurs:

```
gpl origin master
      ^      ^
 tab ok      doesn't tab
```